# Why Webdav loses connection each reboot?

Tags: windows, web-hosting, cpanel, webdav

Hostgator told me on a support call over a year ago that Windows 7 had issues with Webdav because of digest authentication. They also said that future versions of Windows would solve the problems with Webdav.

However Windows 10 is giving me the same grief. I don't know if the problem lies with Windows 10 or Hostgator.

Windows 10 typically loses the mapped Webdav connection on each reboot. I'll often have to reboot 8 or more times to get Webdav to connect. Each time I will run their connection script to connect. However Windows responds with an error that I can't access the network path because I don't have permissions.

I'm getting really tired of deleting the mapped drive and rebooting a dozen times.

The site uses cPanel and it is using digest authentication.

Update:
I have migrated to a new provider that is much more up to date than my previous hosting company.  The problems persist, so it doesn't seem to be an issue that is solely their responsibility.

Sometimes if I delete the connection before reboot, it can be reconnected afterwards.  Sometimes it still takes multiple reboots.

Comment: It sounds like a pain in the butt! I fully understand. I wish I had an answer for you. At least I can up-vote to get you some attention.

Comment: Windows is always a pain. between crashes and now a rather cheap looking user interface, I switched to linux years ago.  Even someone else has issues with windows 10: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oolxnc_8_Sk

Comment: Sorry but this is a common windows issue that occurs on their entire range of versions. You can use startup scripts, and other things to resolve the issue, another quick fix is to use BitKinex or similar client.